# How to write new line with drawText() below code magneto 2?

Tags: magento2, module, shipping

**Anyone plz help me**

[image]

```
  $Commenthistory = "Order Comment History";
        $page->drawText($Commenthistory, 20, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
        //$page->drawText(__('Order Comment History'.PHP_EOL), 20, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
        foreach ($invoice->getOrder()->getStatusHistoryCollection() as $status){
            $textChunk = wordwrap(strip_tags($status->getComment()), 410, "\n");
            foreach(explode("\n", $textChunk) as $textLine){
                if ($textLine!=='') {
                    $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($textLine)), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                    $this->y -= 15;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below,

```
$Commenthistory = "Order Comment History";
$page->drawText($Commenthistory, 20, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
$this->y -= 15;
foreach ($invoice->getOrder()->getStatusHistoryCollection() as $status){
    $textChunk = wordwrap(strip_tags($status->getComment()), 410, "\n");
    foreach(explode("\n", $textChunk) as $textLine){
        if ($textLine!=='') {
            $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($textLine)), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
            $this->y -= 15;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much its working

Comment: Glad to help you

Comment: are you there one more question

Comment: yes, please share

Comment: Sir how to add custom text in header invoice shipping PDF

Comment: Please ask another question for this, so others can't get confused for the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103132/discussion-between-ranjeet-gautam-and-nalin-savaliya).